# Pointer arithmetics in two dimensional array (C++)

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I've got a strange C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
     int tab[][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} };
     int *a = tab[0];
     printf( "%d %d %d", *a++, *a++, *a++ );
     return 0;
}
```

And I've got a question: why the output is 
`3 2 1`. 
Could you explain this pointer arithmetics? Thanks.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Duplicate of 1m+ questions

Comment: I suspect you are seeing first dimension, second dimension, first value. Should be easy to confirm by changing dimensions and values. Agree with Chris- this is compiler dependent and undefined.

Comment: @Floris: No, you cannot reason about it.  Order of function argument evaluation is *unspecified*. Modifying a variable more than once before encountering a sequence point results in *undefined behavior*.  The terms *unspecified* and *undefined* have different meanings.

Comment: @Floris: Yes, it does.  The commas in a function call are *not* examples of the comma operator, i.e., they are not sequence points.

Comment: OK - I was wrong, @EdS. is right. My apologies.